# Where is V15 and how do I find it?

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle, aeronautical-charts, airways, faa-knowledge-test

My question: Where is V15 and how do I find it?

The question referred to in the practice test:

> Refer to the figure 21, area 2 below: What is the floor of controlled airspace along V15?

The correct answer was 1200 ft AGL.

[image: Figure 21 full Section Chart]

[image: Figure 21, area 2 zoom]

I want to thank @757toga, and @JScarry for the help on this. I made an 88 on my Drone certification that I took today (10/11/2018)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a notation for V15 (low altitude IFR airway) in the southern portion of the top map in your question.

[image]

V15 is a Federal Airway, normally used for IFR operations and shown on IFR charts as well as VFR Sectionals. Federal Airways, unless otherwise notated, begin at 1200 AGL. These airways are Class E airspace. If you look in the legend of your Sectional Chart it describes this airspace.

Comment: Oh wow! Thanks, I did not see that at all.
Can you explain where they got 1200 AGL from?

Comment: @crazydaze: V15 is a Federal Airway, normally used for IFR operations and shown on IFR charts as well as VFR Sectionals.  Federal Airways, unless otherwise notated, begin at 1200 AGL. These airways are Class E airspace.  If you look in the legend of your Sectional Chart it describes this airspace.

Comment: Thanks! I'll be sure to remember this for my test in the next couple of days.

Comment: Good luck! I hope you do well.

Comment: @757toga - I added the text of your comment to your answer, in case the comment itself is ever deleted some time in the future.

Comment: @Crazydaze Since you are studying for the test, you also need to know that: “A Federal airway includes the airspace within parallel boundary lines
4 NM to each side of the centerline.”

Comment: @JScarry - good comment above, but it's important to ensure that the questioner knows that in the entire area (not just the 4nm to either side of V15 ) Class E [controlled airspace] exists and begins at 1200' AGL.  The exception, as shown on the map excerpt, are the areas to the west of V15 that are surrounded in magenta color depicting Class E [controlled airspace] beginning at 700' AGL.